# How to create an android app using HTML 5

Tags: android, html

Can we create android applications using HTML5?

Comment: Would you share the experience? What was your choice?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/). It is a HTML5 compliant framework to build application for touch devices.

Comment: We have to install this software or any plugins for eclipse or itself only IDE ?

Comment: It has got only the JavaScript and CSS. No installation is needed. You can use eclipse with JavaScript support for the development

Comment: it's free trial?

Answer (score 49):

You can write complete apps for almost any smartphone platform (Android, iOS,...) using Phonegap. (http://www.phonegap.com)

It is an open source framework that exposes native capabilities to a web view, so that you can do anything a native app can do.

This is very suitable for cross platform development if you're not building something that has to be pixel perfect in every way, or is very hardware intensive.

If you are looking for UI Frameworks that can be used to build such apps, there is a wide range of different libraries. (Like Sencha, jQuery mobile, ...)

And to be a little biased, there is something I built as well: http://www.m-gwt.com

Comment: Does phonegap let you compile your web-app (written in HTML) into an APK for use on android phones? If it does, do they charge for this?

Answer (score 18):

Here is a starting point for developing Android apps with HTML5.  The HTML code will be stored in the "assets/www" folder in your Android project.

https://github.com/jakewp11/HTML5_Android_Template.git

Comment: thas excellent. How can you communicate android native functions with your UI?

Comment: @user1532587 - In the MyWebViewClient java class, you can add custom handling in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method.

Comment: Are there some limitations with this approach? I think I remember there were some tasks you could not perform due to security reasons. IIRC it was about cookies and/or local storage... or am I completely wrong on this?

Comment: @jj_ In my experience I haven't been limited by using this approach.  I am still able to use the GPS functionality, local storage and other hardware with some work-arounds.  I don't typically use this approach when developing, as I prefer to develop natively, but I know some people just want to quickly turn their website into an app, so I made this template.

Comment: Is ECILPSE required for this?

Comment: @Badrush no, you can run it on Android Studio with few project settings change, also you can see [Migrate to Android Studio from Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html).

Answer (score 9):

When people talk about HTML5 applications they're most likely talking about writing just a simple web page or embedding a web page into their app (which will essentially provide the user interface). For the later there are different frameworks available, e.g. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/start/#android). These are used to provide more than the default browser features (e.g. multi touch) as well as allowing the app to run seamingly "standalone" and without the browser's navigation bars etc.

Answer (score 7):

You can use WebView and create a app that put your site inside.
https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/gettingstarted

Answer (score 0):

you can use webview in android  that will use chrome browser Or you can try Phonegap or sencha Touch

Comment: This is a collection of the core keywords from other, upvoted, older answers.

Comment: but sencha has a trial one instead of open source (totally not free).

Answer (score 0):

The [WebIntoApp.com](https://www.webintoapp.com) V.2 allows you to convert HTML5 / JS / CSS into a mobile app for Android APK (free) and iOS.

(I'm the author)