# Using HTML to build phone application

Tags: android

I have tried some App Builder to build the mobile application such as Seattle Cloud, now I want try to build an android application without using the App Builder, but I figured out the page's extension is .HTML in the App Builder, but when I using Android Studio to build the app, the layout is using XML. I have experience to develop web application using PHP and now I want try to build an Android Application to view information from my web application, I feel confused, How should I start?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) for hybrid app development using web technologies such as CSS, HTML, JavaScript and jQuery.

Other similar options available are [Titanium SDK](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/titanium-sdk/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch), but you will take time to get well with them. They are better than Phonegap in some areas, also device api support is available.

Whatever framework you use to build hybrid apps, you will have their respective js files and css to achieve functions. Some combine with PhoneGap in the end to use device api's, so it is better to go with PhoneGap or something like Titanium or Sencha. You may also have a look at [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), it uses AngularJS, HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebView. It's a view that displays web pages. You can use local html files as well as a URL. For more information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0):

Android works in a very different compared to web apps. the design of the application is done in XML which will create native UI components and will be much faster the HTML counterparts.

There are different frameworks for developing an android app based on HTML/JavaScript

1. Sencha touch
2. Phonegap
3. Appcelerator Titanium (Although this may not be a pure HTML framework)

see: [How to create an android app using HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045355/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-html-5)

But compared to apps based on HTML frameworks, native apps will be faster, consumes lower memory.

Visit http://developer.android.com/training/index.html to get started.

Comment: hi, so application builed by Seattle Cloud is called web app?

Comment: @ReiTee I haven't used Seattle Cloud, so IDK what it generates, But if generated content runs on a Web Browser (i.e., by extend uses a WebView to show the UI) then it's a web app.

Comment: I am not sure about that too, after I edit all the .html page , I can publish to Play Store, other can download from it

Comment: ya, it looks like it generates a web app.

Comment: can you give me example of web app and native app?